# I want to omit specifying default namespace using libxml-ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, libxml-ruby

I have questions about libxml-ruby.
There is a xml file "sample.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://***" xmlns:r="http://???">
    <sheetData>
        <row><v>1</v></row>
    </sheetData>
</worksheet>
```

I want to deal with nodes without specifying default namespace like below.

```
xml = XML::Document.file('sample.xml')
sheet_data = xml.find_first('sheetData')
```

Of course, I can do it like below.

```
NS = {
  main: 'http://***',
  r: 'http://???',
}
sheet_data = xml.find_first('main:sheetData', NS)
```

But I want to omit string of default namespace.
I tried some properties and methods belongs to XML::Namespace[s], but not effected.

And one more problem when I save a xml file.

```
ns = XML::Namespace.new(xml.root, 'main', 'http://***')
row = XML::Node.new('row', nil, ns)
sheet_data << row
xml.save("sample.xml")
```

Published like below.

```
<row><v>1</v></row>
<main:row/>
```

I want that it's omitted string of "main:". 
So I do this, but it's really ugly.

```
open('sample.xml', 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(xml.to_s.gsub(/(<\/?)main:/, '\1'))
end
```

Do you have any good idea?

Comment: Could you tell me the final output,you are looking for? And if possible go with `Nokogiri`,it will help you out..

Comment: Hi, Arup. My desired result is that no string of default namespace in  published file. I hope "<row/>" but not "<main:row/>". I knew about Nokogori but don't want to use it very much.